# Why don't Terminal.app profile plists set the ANSI normal and bright colors?

Tags: macos, terminal, color-scheme

When I download a profile/theme for Terminal.app (say, zenburn.terminal or solarized.terminal), invariably I get the following scenario:

- The background, text, bold text, selection, and cursor colors are all set properly (or, they look right to me anyway). Other settings like cursor style are set as well.
- However, the colors under the "ANSI Colors" section are never change from the default blacks, reds, greens, yellows, blues, etc.

Does anyone know why this is?